# Azure DevOps Pipeline Grunt Task Not Taking WorkingDirectory Input

Tags: gruntjs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm just starting some experiments to replace our TeamCity builds with Azure DevOps Pipelines.  One of my projects has a Grunt dependency, so I have created a task:

```
- task: Grunt@0  
  displayName: 'Run Grunt task bower install'
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: $(webDir)
    targets: bower:install
```

I've read the documentation for the grunt task, and it says that I can provide a working directory, but everything I've done so far only yields an error message with no particularly helpful feedback:

```
## [error] Not found gruntfile: D:\a\1\s\gruntfile.js
```

Here's a few of the workingDirectory inputs I've tried:

```
    workingDirectory: 'Web'
    workingDirectory: '.\\Web'
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\\Web'
    workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Web
```

Ultimately, I'm expecting that putting a string in the workingDirectory will have some impact, but I'm obviously doing something wrong, and can't seem to see what it is.

One last thing, I created a few new tasks to run before this grunt task, just to see what the CWD is, and to validate my knowledge of workingDirectory for other tasks.

```
- script: cwd
  displayName: show working dir1
  workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\\Web Store'

- script: cwd
  displayName: show working dir2
  workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Web Store

- script: cwd
  displayName: show working dir3
  workingDirectory: $(webStoreDir)


- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: show working dir4
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: $(webStoreDir)
    script : cwd
```

In all 4 cases, working directory is passed to the Cmd.exe  ...

Evidently the "grunt" task operates under some different concepts, but I'm  at a loss to work them out.

How can I get the grunt task to accept the working directory?

Comment: Try `cwd` instead...

Comment: Or try `gruntFile : $(BuildSourcesDirectory)\Web Store\gruntfile.json`